# WSO2 IS: user can login from one pc only at a time

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 Identity Server, I've a user whose credentials are shared between some people.
When I login using these credentials, everyone else logs out

Is there anyway to change this ?

Comment: Are you using JWT access tokens? What is the Identity Server version?

Comment: Yes, im using JWT, version is 5.11.0

Comment: I've added this line in deployment.toml [authentication.authenticator.session_handler.parameters]
max_session_count = "100", then restarted wso2.but diodnt work

Comment: if the sessions were revoked due to max_session_count configuration, it should show a popup and ask the user whether to terminate existing sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are having JWT access tokens configured, it revokes the previously issued access token and issues a new access token when the same user tries to log in to the same application again. Because WSO2 IS has a constraint that the same user, same application, and same OAuth2 scope combination could have only one active access token.

To mitigate the issue you are facing while trying to login to the same application from different devices, you can configure "Access Token Binding Type" as "SSO Session Based". Then it will allow you to have access tokens per each SSO session on each browser/device.

You can find this configuration under the OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration section of the service provider. Also, read more from the [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-oauth2-openid-connect-single-sign-on/).

Comment: I've changed Access Token Binding Type to  SSO Session Based and restarted the server from the web console, but still i cant login from multiple browsers

Comment: is SSO session available only for Supported grant types: Code, I'm currently using password grant type

Comment: Yes, it is not supported for password grant since there is no SSO session created for password grant. Then the viable solution would be adding a scope to the token request which is unique for each device. Then the tokens issued for other devices won't be revoked since the scope is different.